# Once I log into Stackoverflow, can I get Google to somehow automatically log off my account?

Tags: discussion, openid, login, google

I use Google as my OpenID provider. Once I log into Stackoverflow with my gmail account, can I get Google to somehow automatically log off my account?  I prefer not to have my personal google account always logged in. It's not a big deal going to gmail and clicking log off, but if there is a simpler way that would be good.

Comment: Is this really a meta question?

Comment: It's a feature request, else I would have closed it as being off-topic on Super User

Answer (score 1):

No. StackOverflow cannot in anyway affect Google's cookies.

StackOverflow can only control the cookies for stackoverflow.com, and subdomains. Because Google is a completely different domain, StackOverflow is unable to add, modify, read, or delete their cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like this, one of the nice things about StackOverflow is that you can use the alternate OpenID feature to switch your account to a different OpenID provider that has the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

It'll just be an AuthToken. Only of use to connect your browser to your Google ID. You're not logged in to Google in the normal sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this, by my understanding, is behaviour as designed.

The point of OpenID is that you are able to login using one set of credentials and remain logged in to multiple sites using the same account.

If you do not want accounts to be linked in this way then you need to separate them rather than have them be associated via OpenID or similar schemes.